# How to differentiate a function w.r.t another symbolic function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

**Using the code,**

```
syms x(t) 
y=x^2
diff(y,t)
diff(y,x)
```

**I get the following error:**

```
2*D(x)(t)*x(t)
Error using sym/diff (line 26)
All arguments, except for the first one, must not be symbolic functions.
```

**Is there a way to tackle this? Thanks for your time.**

Comment: See my answer to this very similar question: [How to implement a derivative of a symbolic function by a 'symfun' in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085362/how-to-implement-a-derivative-of-a-symbolic-function-by-a-symfun-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much about the Symbolic Math Toolbox, but taking a derivative wrt to a function does not seem to be supported (at least in a direct fashion) for [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/diff.html).

You can substitute a variable, compute a derivative, and substitute the function back. Like so:

```
syms z
subs(diff(subs(y,x,z),z),z,x)

ans(t) = 2*x(t)
```