# How to implement a derivative of a symbolic function by a 'symfun' in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Here is my Matlab program:

```
syms x(t) t;
f = x^2 + 5;
```

And the result of `f`:

```
f(t) = x(t)^2 + 5
```

Both `f` and `x` are of class `symfun` in Matlab. I want the result of df/dx, which is equal to `2*x(t)`. 
I tried this in Matlab:

```
diff(f, x);
```

and got the following errors:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: The variable is
invalid. [stdlib::diff]
Error in sym/diff (line 57)
    R = mupadmex('symobj::diff', S.s, x.s,
    int2str(n));
```

How can df/dx be obtained in Matlab?

Comment: You need to do `diff(x^2+5)` to obtain `2*x`. You can also do `diff(f)`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: that's the derivative with respect to time, `t`. The OP is interested in the derivative with respect to `x(t)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer versions of Matlab (I'm using R2014b) the error message is clearer:

> Error using **sym/diff** (line 26)
>   All arguments, except for the first one, must not be symbolic functions.

So, it looks like [`sym/diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) cannot take a derivative with respect to what the documentation calls an abstract or arbitrary [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html), i.e., one without a definition. This limitation is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but the various input patterns allude to it.

**Workaround 1**: Simple functions, independent variable `t` only appears in differentiated symfun

I haven't found any workaround that is particularly elegant. If `t` only appears in your variable of interest (here `x(t)`), and not on its own or in other abstract symbolic functions, you can differentiate with respect to time `t` and then cancel out the extra terms. For example:

```
syms t x(t) y(t) z
f1 = x^2+5;
f2 = x^2+z^2+5;
f3 = x^2+y^2+z^2+5+t;
dxdt = diff(x,t);
df1 = diff(f1,t)/dxdt
df2 = diff(f2,t)/dxdt
df3 = diff(f3,t)/dxdt
```

which returns the requisite `2*x(t)` for the first two cases, but not the third, for the reasons stated above. You may need to apply [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) in some cases to fully divide out the `D(x)(t)` terms.

**Workaround 2**: More robust, but more complicated method

Using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) multiple times, you can replace the symbolic function in question with a standard symbolic variable, differentiate, and swap it back. For example:

```
syms t x(t) y(t) z
f3 = x^2+y^2+z^2+5+t;
xx = sym('x');
df3 = subs(diff(subs(f3,x,xx),xx),xx,x)
```

which also returns `2*x(t)` for the third case above. But I think this is kind of an ugly hack.

It is kind of ridiculous that Matlab can't do this – Mathematica has no such problem. It appears that MuPAD itself has this limitation. You might consider [filing a feature request](https://www.mathworks.com/accesslogin/login.do?uri=%2Faccesslogin%2Fsso%2Fsaml%3Ftype%3DSFEXT_SSO%26forward%3Dcp_case_new) with The MathWorks.

Comment: 1.The method by using `df = diff(f,t)diff(x,t)` is just suitable for calculating the function `f` of just variable `x(t)`. In the second example mentioned, where `f = x(t)^2+y(t)^2+5+t`, the `f` is the function of `x(t)`,`y(t)` and `t`, the result is not the one I want by using `df = diff(f,t)diff(x,t)`, so it's limited and not feasible for all possible functions.  2.I tried the second method of using `subs`, just as you said, it's kind of an ugly hack. However, it is a feasible way of addressing my   problems.@horchler

Comment: @Saking: Yes, that is what I tried to say and is why I provided the second workaround. I've reworded the answer a bit and added a few more examples. Hopefully it will be a bit clearer.