# Partial differential equation in Matlab (incorrect solution)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Let's define function `x(t)`, its time derivative `xdot(t)`, and expression `T` that is dependent on them:

```
syms t x(t)
xdot(t) = diff(x,t);
T = (xdot + x)^2;
```

We can all agree that partial derivative of `T` with respect to `x` is `∂T/∂x = 2*(xdot+x)`. However, if I do this in Matlab I get wrong answer:

```
dT_dx  = subs( diff( subs(T,x,'x'), 'x' ), 'x', x);
>> dT_dx  = 2 x(t)
```

Note that it returns the correct answer for `∂T/∂xdot`:

```
dT_dxdot = subs( diff( subs(T,xdot,'x1'), 'x1' ), 'x1', xdot);
>> dT_dxdot = 2*x(t) + 2*diff(x(t), t)
```

It looks like Matlab ignores the product `2*x*xdot`, when calculating derivatives in terms of lower order variables (`x`), but it doesn't ignore this product when calculating derivative in terms of higher order variables (`xdot`). If we redefined the expression `T` as `T = (100 + x)^2`, we would get `∂T/∂x`:

```
>> ans = 2 x(t) + 200
```

Thus, after having swapped `xdot` with a constant we now obtain correct answer.

*Comments:*

- I utilized double substitution in order to use the `diff` function,
  because `diff(T,x)` returns an error. I found this approach
  [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312204).
- Expanding the expression `T` before calculating the derivative does not work –
  we still get incorrect answer.
- I also tried the `functionalDerivative` function, but it returns the incorrect
  answer as well.

**Question**

How can one reliably calculate partial and absolute derivatives of `T`, especially `∂T/∂x`?

Is `subs( diff(subs()  ) )` a good approach, or is there a better way, and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, taking the derivative of an abstract `symfun` like `x(t)` is not the same as taking the derivative of a symbolic variable like `x` (assuming `x(t)` hasn't already been declared in the scope) – see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086016/2278029) for more. One needs to be very careful substituting like you're doing. The problem arrises because `x(t)` gets substituted for `'x'` inside of `diff(x,t)` (`xdot(t)`) too, i.e., the first substitution in your code, `subs(T,x,'x')`, already returns an incorrect result relative to what you expect.

You can try this:

```
syms x(t)
xdot(t) = diff(x,t);
T = (xdot + x)^2;
x1 = {x,xdot};
x2 = {'x','xdot'};
dT_dx = subs(diff(subs(T,x1,x2),'x'),x2,x1)
```

which returns `2*x(t) + 2*diff(x(t), t)`.

Comment: I will look into substitution issue, because this must be the case. On the other hand, `functionalDerivative` does not return required answer since there is second derivative of x and what I need is partial derivative of T against x, that is exactly `∂T/∂x = 2*(xdot+x)`.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed that. I'm looking into it. I've also updated by answer with a `subs` solution.